# How to get canonical file without using wget?

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, wget, offline, scanning, canonical-link

I am trying to get OVAL xml file from the following link:

https://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/oval/com.ubuntu.xenial.cve.oval.xml

I am using a Ubuntu 16.04 virtual machine offline, and I can't do:

```
wget https://people.canonical.com/../com.ubuntu.xenial.cve.oval.xml
```

How can I download this file ?